# How to add a line to multiple text files under different sub-directories only if the line doesn't exist?

Tags: linux, shell, perl, unix, grep

I have a directory called "technology" and under "technology" directory I have multiple sub-directories nested up to two levels max.

Under every sub-directory I have at least one "*.txt" file which could have up to 20 to 30 lines entry in it.

Now, I want to add "Remarks" line in every *.txt files spanning across multiple sub-directories only if the line is not there already.

I am getting list of all files under sub-directory using:

```
find ./ -name '*.txt'
```

I am using below mention Perl script to update entries, with new remarks as shown below.

```
/technology$ perl -p -i -e 's/Remarks.*/Remarks: NEW Value/'   'find ./ -name *.txt'
```

Problem with above script is that it only updates the existing remarks field.

How can I add an entry (one liner remarks) to ONLY those files that don't actually have it already?

I want to add line to only those files that don't contain a "Remarks line".

Answer (score 3):

It isn't entirely clear if you want to update the rows containing `Remarks` in the files that already contain such a line or you want to leave those files unchanged and only add a line at the end of those file that don't contain remarks.

Fortunately, there isn't much difference.  This code should work for "edit existing `Remarks` lines; add a new `Remarks` line if there isn't one already":

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -i

use strict;
use warnings;

my $num_remarks = 0;

while (<>)
{
    $num_remarks++ if s/Remarks.*/Remarks: NEW Value $$/;
    print;
}
continue
{
    if (eof)
    {
        print "Remarks: NEW Value $$\n" if $num_remarks == 0;
        $num_remarks = 0;
    }
}
```

The alternative requirement "leave existing `Remarks` lines unchanged; add a new `Remarks` line if there isn't one" can be handled with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -i

use strict;
use warnings;

my $num_remarks = 0;

while (<>)
{
    $num_remarks++ if m/Remarks/;   # m// instead of s///
    print;
}
continue
{
    if (eof)
    {
        print "Remarks: NEW Value $$\n" if $num_remarks == 0;
        $num_remarks = 0;
    }
}
```

There are probably shorter ways to write this code.  Both variants include the PID of the Perl process in the 'Remarks' line when it is added.  This makes it easier to see when things are changed.

Comment: I edit the question. and mention that i want to only add a line at the end of those file that don't contain remarks.

Comment: How this solution works for all of the subdirectories under technology directory?